# Combine multiple Mono List into one

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm currently working on a project that involves a bit of reactive programming.

I have to call multiple validate methods in parallel and return `true` or `false` based on validation response. The goal is to combine the `List` into a single `Mono<List<ApiErrorEntity>>` in order to validate the failure list, not sure how to combine them in parallel call. I don’t want to get the results with `getT1()`, `getT2` etc. because I will be adding more validation method latter, I am looking to get `Flux` of `List` for compassion kindly help

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ValidationService {
   
    public Mono<Boolean> validate(UserRequest userRequest, String empno, ServerHttpRequest request) {
               
        List<ApiErrorEntity> validationFailures=  validateUserInfo(userRequest, empno, request)
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(validationFailures)) {
            throw new ValidationException(validationFailures);
        }
             
        return Mono.just(true);
    }
        
    public  List<ApiErrorEntity> validateUserInfo(UserRequest userRequest , String empno, ServerHttpRequest request) {
              
        List<ApiErrorEntity> validationFailures = new ArrayList<>();
              
        List<ApiErrorEntity> dateList= validateUserDate(userRequest .flag(),userRequest.enrollDate(),validationFailures);
        List<ApiErrorEntity> userList= validateUser(userRequest , empno, request,validationFailures);

        // here i need to call two methods and have to return list of errors, not sure how to combine them by making parallel call. i dont want tuple.getT1 and tuple.getT2..
        // since I have to include more methods latter               
        List<ApiErrorEntity> result= Mono.zip(dateList,userList)
        return result;
    }
        
    private   List<ApiErrorEntity>   validateUserDate(Boolean flag, LocalDate enrollDate,  List<ApiErrorEntity> validationFailures) {
               
        if (flag== null || !flag) {
            if (enrollDate== null) {
                validationFailures.add(createApiError("regDate", "No date information provided"));
                       
            }
            if (enrollDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
                validationFailures.add(createApiError("regDate", "date cannot be in the past"));
                        
            }
                   
        return validationFailures;
    }
        
    private  List<ApiErrorEntity>  validateUser(UserRequest paymentRequest, ServerHttpRequest request,List<ApiErrorEntity> validationFailures) {
     
        userService.getUserDetails(request)
                .flatMap(userDetails -> {
                    if(!userDetails.getIsActive()) {
                        validationFailures.add(createApiError( "userDetails", "user is not active "));
                    } else if (userDetails.age >55) < 0) {
                        validationFailures.add(createApiError( "userDetails", "Not Eligible user"));
                    }
                    return Mono.just(validationFailures);
                })
                .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
                        e -> {
                            if(e.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                                        validationFailures.add(createApiError( "userDetails","Invalid user account"));
                            }
                            return Mono.error(e);
                        });
        return  validationFailures;
        
    }
        
    private ApiErrorEntity createApiError(String name, String reason) {
        return new ApiErrorEntity(name, reason);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Read tags before using them please. The mono tag isn't for Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `Flux<List<ApiErrorEntity>>` from your List's `dateList` and `userList` you can create it with:

```java
Flux<List<ApiErrorEntity>> result = Flux.just(dateList, userList);
```

Then you can concat the elements emitted by `result` into a single `List`:

```java
Mono<List<ApiErrorEntity>> concat = result.collectList()
    .flatMap(lists -> Mono.just(lists.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())));;
```

Alternatively you could concat the List's first:

```java
Mono<List<ApiErrorEntity>> singleList = Mono.just(
        Stream.concat(dateList.stream(), userList.stream()).toList());
```

But if you want to call validators parallel on the List's emitted by `result` you need to convert the `Flux` into a `ParallelFlux` first:

```java
ParallelFlux<List<ApiErrorEntity>> parallel = result.parallel();
```